# Newpage between tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I'm trying to draw in tikz.

The aim is to create a document with a first page with the title and other infos.
Each of the other page is a wiremap a of type of cable.

I use python to generate the tex code. And I need to start a new page between each wiremap (between each `tikzpicture`).

So I tried to use a simple newpage, but MikTeX says to me this error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
            \endgroup
l.12 \newpage

?
```

My TeX file is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[green] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[blue] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need the option tikz or multi: `\documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer today it's the third time that when I'm trying to write a comment, at the same moment the answer in my mind is written by someone faster than me! :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is great. This should be written as an answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In such case, the `tikz`  pictures are automatically appearing in separated pages, which means the command `\newpage` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

I provide a simple method to control **page breaks** in the `standalone` class.

## All pictures in the same page

As a MWE I take the following code, based on the question, where three pictures are generated in the same page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[green] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[blue] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

## Each picture in a different page

Taking @Ulrike Fischer's solution, which is just adding the option `tikz` to the document class, i.e., changing the line `\documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}` by `\documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}` each picture appears in a different page.

[image]

## Total Control of Page Breaks

If we want to arbitrarily insert page breaks between the pictures. For example, to put one picture in the first page and two pictures together in the last page. We can generate a *dummy* environment, e.g., `standalonepage` and group the pictures that belong to the same page. As in the example before.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\newenvironment{standalonepage}{}{} %Dummy environment that contains pictures in the same page
\standaloneenv{standalonepage} %The dummy environment is make known to the stand alone class
\begin{document}

%First Page
\begin{standalonepage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (21,29.7);
    \draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
    \draw[green] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{standalonepage}

%Second Page
\begin{standalonepage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
    \draw[blue] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
    \draw[red] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{standalonepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution for this kind of document could be [`incgraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/incgrpah). Its documentation abstract says:

> `incgraph` provides tools for including graphics on full paper size. The
>   graphics can be centered for a given paper format or the paper may be
>   resized to the graphics dimensions. The main use case for the package
>   `incgraph` is to transform one or many scans or taken pictures to a PDF
>   document. It can also be applied for full paper size `LaTeX` created
>   graphics. The package `incgraph` provides a tool box with basic macros
>   and a convenience user interface which wraps the well-known
>   includegraphics. Also, bookmarking is especially supported.

As an alternative to `standalone` in this particular case offers the advantage of having the whole document (title page and figures) in a unique `.tex` file.

As it's shown in following example, `TikZ` figures can be included and they keep it's own size or can be included into a formal page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{incgraph}
%
\title{Cable catalogue}
\author{Anonymous}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%
\begin{inctext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[green] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}

\begin{inctext}[currentpaper]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (1,1) rectangle (5,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}

\begin{inctext}[border=1cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (1,1) rectangle (5,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}

\begin{inctext}[border=3mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}

\incgraph{frog.jpg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following code simulates your case. Compile the following with `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{figure.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,multi]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (21,29.7);
\draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[green] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (21,29.7);
\draw[blue] (1,1) rectangle (20,28.7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex figure}


\title{My title}
\author{I am}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\Insert}[2][1]{\includegraphics[scale=#1,page=#2]{figure}\newpage}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\Insert[0.5]{1}
\Insert[0.5]{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the page don't fill the whole a4paper. If I change the scale to 1.0 instead of 0.5, the picture isn't centered.  Best Regards.  Doom