# Change the page size as image size

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to change the size of the page as same as the image size. Here is the link:

https://www.overleaf.com/6438471362ynzdrqvsjyhj

Comment: My suggestion: compiling standalone image, then insert into main.tex with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}`

Comment: Use package [`incgraph`](https://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph). Some examples here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287054/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405960/1952

Comment: My previous comment is valid if you want to get a physical page as large as an included image, but after looking at your example, I'm not sure about your question. Please make it clearer. By the way, you should clean your preamble, a lot of packages are loaded two or more and a lot of packages are not necessary to get the figure.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document.  You can determine the image size using a savebox.